# javascript mouse cursor change on page load in firefox browser 3.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouse, cursor

Hi in case of full page submit a trasparent div id coming and changing the cursor to 'wait' . Now when the page is getting submitted and new page is coming up cursor still remains to 'wait' not changing to default until mouse is moved in Firefox

Here is simple html click on show button div is coming when user move mouse over the div cursor is changing as wait cursor. Now when  this page is loaded again pressing F5 cursor remain as wait cursor in firefox its working fine in IE is there any way to make the cursor as default on pageload in Firefox

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <style>
        body {
            cursor:default;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"> </script>
    <script>
        var test = true;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#maindiv').css('display','none')
        });
        function showDiv() {
            $('#maindiv').css('display','block')
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="divBody" style="background-color:red;width:500px;height:500px" >aa
        <div id="maindiv" style="background-color:#999999;height:100$;width:400px;height:400px;cursor:wait">
            sss
        </div>aa
   </div>
    <input  type="button" value="show" onclick="showDiv()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Validate. Validate. Validate. http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: I think there is already a bug reported for this issue : [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=511151)

Answer (score 0):

Could you use an animated image to give the user feedback instead of changing the cursor?

[ajaxload.info](http://ajaxload.info/) has some great examples.

Answer (score 0):

thats some messy code...

why not use an image or, css to display a div on top of everything else with transparent background and `cursor: wait;` on your css or style tag then show that div when ever you wish...

HTML
`<div id="modal">&nbsp;</div>`
`<input id="test" type="text" />`

JQuery

```
$('#modal').css({cursor: 'wait'}).width($(document).width()).height($(document).height());
$('#test').bind('click',function (){$('#modal').show()})
```

I have not tested this so ... in theory it should work ... if not try and change body width and height to "100%"

take care