# Can I change mouse cursor while clicked on IE with jquery?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, cursor

I know that Internet Explorer [triggers cursor changes only after the mouse moves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100944/for-a-div-with-a-css-defined-cursor-ie-doesnt-automatically-reset-the-cursor-i), but it seems like it prevents such changes while the mouse is clicked.

Here's an example I created: http://jsfiddle.net/AfKxt/18/

I created a CSS with the new cursor

```
.mouseMoving{
    cursor: url("http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-extern.php?id=51958"), default;
}
```

When mousedown is called over a particular div, I add a class "buttonDown" and remove it when button is up.

If I move the mouse while the button is down (i.e. the "buttonDown" class is existent), then I add the CSS class with the new cursor.

```
var m_node = $("#mainDiv");
m_node
.mousedown(function(){
    m_node.addClass('buttonDown');
 })
.mouseup(function(){
    m_node.removeClass('buttonDown');   
    m_node.removeClass('mouseMoving');
})
.mousemove(function(){
    if(m_node.hasClass('buttonDown')){
      m_node.addClass('mouseMoving');
    }
});
```

Everything works fine with FF and Chrome, but not with (big news, right?) IE.

Does anyone know why I'm getting this?

Comment: seems like IE only supports `.cur` and `.ani` urls for [cursor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/cursor/url#Compatibility_with_other_browsers)

Comment: check the url, that is a .cur file. I use another file locally, that one is only for jsfiddle but it's not this the problem. You can check verify this if you change the class when you click on the div.